# How to get vpn pptp client ip in GRE packets?

Tags: vpn, pptp, point-to-point-protocol

I hava captured some packets for pptp client, but how to get the virtual ip of pptp client? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngrep -d eth1 '.*' ! port 22

Eth1  is just example      port 22 is some

You can  use ngrep