# How to disable encryption for the remote vpn clients in PPTP?

Tags: pptp, point-to-point-protocol

I find there is one compress PPP packet in GRE packet, so how to get the PPP packet without

encryption and compression ? thanks

Comment: You seem to be asking the same question in a number of different ways, see eg http://serverfault.com/questions/207737/how-to-get-vpn-pptp-client-ip-in-gre-packets .  Are you asking generally how to break PPTP encryption given only the ciphertext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pptp  is   isnt  crypted  (openvpn using ssl, but  default pptp configuration  isnt using)   you can use ngrep  or tcpdump  or another  sniffing  to cache pakage.